# external sound card TLV320AIC3101 in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi3, i2c, alsa

I'm working on a project to add an external sound card to Raspberry Pi 3.

The sound card we use has a sound codec with IC **TLV320AIC3101**. This IC has an I2C control interface and an I2S interface. I want to record and play audio using this IC in **Raspberry Pi 3**. I think I should work with Alsa.
My project is very similar to the project of adding the wm8960 module to Raspberry Pi.

I need help. please guide me

Comment: https://www.ti.com/tool/TLV320AIC31XX-DRIVERS it seems to already have support in Linux.

Comment: I saw the link
Do you think I should get help from TI?